# What is the complexity of the matrix multiplication closure for a given generating system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity, matrix-theory

Given a generating set of $k$ matrices $X = \{M_1, M_2, \ldots, M_k\}$, with $M_i\in \mathrm{Mat}(\mathbb{C},n)$, what is the worst case complexity for computing the algebraic closure w.r.t. matrix multiplication?

EDIT: In this context, algebraic closure refers to the smallest subalgebra of $\mathrm{Mat}(\mathbb{C},n)$ that contains the generating matrices in $X$.

Given that any matrix algebra in $\mathrm{Mat}(\mathbb{C},n)$ is at max $n^2$-dimensional, can we say that this closure generally lies in polynomial complexity?

Comment: Do you mean you want to compute the semigroup generated by these matrices? If so, in what sense? They could generate infinitely many matrices. Do you want a basis for the subalgebra they span?  That might be more hopeful

Comment: Yes, algebraic closure means that the computation terminates as soon as I have a set of linearly independet matrices that form a basis of a matrix subalgebra of $\mathrm{Mat}(\mathbb{C},n)$.

Comment: You can then do this in a naive way by replacing your matrices by a linearly independent subset B and then at each stage to have some set C of linearly independent matrices in your algebra, take products with B adding to C any product that is not dependent on things you had before and continuing.  You can only do this n^2-|B| (maybe +1) times.  I'm sure there is a better algorithm.

Comment: I see. But doesn't it have to be $n^2$ times since I also have to multiply every element in $B$ with itself too?

Comment: You have to do at most n^2 steps.  Each step might involve |B| multiplications.  Presumably the number of matrices is part of the input as well as the size